# How to deploy Node.js and mongoDB project to normal c panel?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new in node JS, I want to publish my node JS project to my web server. Please help me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks I already fixed the issue. Thanks